# Pyspark Extract one key/value from a JSON column

Tags: json, pyspark

I've seen various question regarding reading JSON from a column in Pyspark.  In all of them it appears the entire schema has to be specified and then to_json is applied and then keys can be referenced easily.

I have a column that has a large number of unique keys in it and I only want to extract the key/value for one key (which isn't present in all rows).  Is there a quick and easy way (outside of using some kind of regexp string parsing function) to extract this key/value by name?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:

```
df.withColumn('newNameOfColumn', f.json_tuple("JSON_COLUMN_AS_STRING", "KEY_YOU_WISH_TO_EXTRACT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm significantly late to the question, but since it popped up on my google search, I suppose I can help others with an alternative solution.

Assuming you have a Dataframe with a column containg the json in string format:

```
data = [("1", '''{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'''), ("2", '''{"key1": "value1_from_id_2"}''')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id", "column_containing_json"))


+---+----------------------+
| id|column_containing_json|
+---+----------------------+
|  1|  {"key1": "value1"...|
|  2|  {"key1": "value1_...|
+---+----------------------+
```

You can read a key inside the json and store it on a new column like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

df = df.withColumn("new_column", get_json_object(df.column_json, f'$.key'))
```

This option is avaliable [since pyspark 1.6](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object.html)